# Apache Sqoop communication link failure

Tags: sqoop

I get the following error when I connect to mysql on one cluster (`aaaaaa1`) and sqooop on a different server (`aaaaaa2`), despite creating a table in mySql with full permissions granted to the other cluster.

Please help me to determine what is the cause of this issue.  Thanks!

```
**$sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://(address of mysql):11000/sqoopdemo --table widgets**
12/10/12 10:42:23 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
12/10/12 10:42:23 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
12/10/12 10:42:23 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:684)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:53)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:473)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:496)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:195)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:179)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:116)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1226)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1051)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:84)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:370)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:456)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:182)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:221)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:230)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:239)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:294)
        ... 32 more
12/10/12 10:42:23 ERROR manager.CatalogQueryManager: Failed to list columns
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:684)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:53)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.getColumnNames(CatalogQueryManager.java:147)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnNames(ClassWriter.java:1198)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1053)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:84)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:370)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:456)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:182)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:221)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:230)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:239)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:294)
        ... 28 more
12/10/12 10:42:23 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.        at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.getColumnNames(CatalogQueryManager.java:163)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnNames(ClassWriter.java:1198)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1053)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:84)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:370)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:456)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:182)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:221)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:230)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:239)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:684)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:53)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.getColumnNames(CatalogQueryManager.java:147)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:294)
```

Answer (score 2):

You seems not to be using parameters --username and --password to specify MySQL username and password which is suspicious. I would recommend explicitly set credentials. Also MySQL is by default running on port 3306 and not 11000, so please make sure that the port is correct.

After that please try to connect to your MySQL box from the same machine as you're running Sqoop using mysql command line utility:

mysql -h (address of mysql) -p 11000 -u (username) -p(password) sqoopdemo

Would be great if you could share output of this command in case that you won't be able to connect to your MySQL box.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the bind-address setting in my.cnf on the server(aaaaaa1), and make sure it's listening on the IP address(or hostname) you're targeting(ip of aaaaaa1). You may also need to ensure skip-networking isn't switched on!
Alternatively (and less securely!) the following will set it up to listen on all addresses - local and remote:
bind-address = 0.0.0.0

It means replace bind-address = 127.0.0.1 with bind-address = 0.0.0.0 in my.cnf file.
my.cnf file is available at /etc/mysql folder. Please restart your mysql server 
before you try to use ip address or machine name.
Just for testing try running this on the command line of aaaaaa1: mysql -h  -u  -p

If the above runs fine, then run the sqoop command on aaaaaa2.
Make sure you have made a user () and have granted the user all the privileges.

This worked for me. Hope, it works for you too! :)

Reference:  http://pavanchalla.blogspot.in/2013/10/mapreduce.html

Answer (score 0):

please run the below sqoop command

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://(address of mysql):3306/sqoopdemo --table widgets

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by giving proper permissions to the ip address:
grant all privileges on *.* to root@192.168.42.1 IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;

There are different IPV4 ip address, make sure that you pick up the correct ip address

Answer (score 0):

I have got solution for this is to **download newest Mysql Connector**.

try this and you will succed - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55365072/8642144

After Downloading just copy the jar file in your sqoop/lib/ directory and try this command

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqooptest --username newuser --password password --table sqoopcheck
```

> localhost - is beacuse i am running on local.
>
> 3306 - mysql default port number
>
> sqooptest - this is my database name(make sure you create database
> manually  via any user or root).
>
> newuser - this is my username for mysql (you can also create new user
> and make sure give him rights).
>
> password - this is my password for newuser .
>
> sqoopcheck - this is the table inside my database(sqooptest).